# Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS blank screen after install

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS from the Ubuntu website and ran the windows installer. It seems like the install completed successfully but when I tried to boot into Ubuntu I just get a blank screen after I select Ubuntu (as opposed to windows). I am guessing my display configuration is not supported but I'm not sure. Is there a way to have the windows installer get the correct drivers for me? I tried a redhat CD and had the same issue.

I have an Nvidia Geforce GTX 460 v2 and I am using the HDMI output to go to a samsung display.

I used an easy sbf linux boot cd to flash an andriod phone and it did not have any problems displaying the simple text in the console mode.

Thanks

Comment: Holding shift before starting up allowed me to go into recovery mode and install the proper drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing nomodeset from the grub menu before you choose Ubuntu to boot. It's under the menu on the bottom right (under F6 I think)

Comment: It looks like the windows installer uses the windows boot menu instead of grub :(

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you should be able to re-install grub by booting off the Ubuntu live CD.  I am no expert on the exact procedure, but there's plenty of examples around, just do a quick search.